# Skipping files when using grep

Tags: bash, grep

How can I modify the following bash code to make it select files by a certain numeric value ? For instance `selcnt=3` would search the pattern every third file, `selcnt=5` would search the pattern every fifth file, etc.

```
grep -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  while read f; do
    echo -e $(tput setaf 46)"==> $f <==\n"$(tput sgr0)
    grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "$f"
    echo ""
  done
```

The intention is to speed up the search process, but keeping the output sectioned one file at a time.  One way to spped the process would be for different runs processing different files, for instance, by skipping files.

```
Run 1: Start from file 1 and skipping two files; 
Run 2: Start from file 2 and skipping two files;  
Run 3: Start from file 2 and skipping two files.
```

As first attempt I have used

```
ist=1; isk=2
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}"  |
  sed -z '${ist}~${isk}!d'  |
  while IFS= read -rd '' fl; do
    printf '%s\n\n' "${grn}==> $fl <==${sgr}"
    grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "$fl"
  done
```

But I am getting the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every third file"? When listed in lexicographic order? What would be the point of this?

Comment: The point will be that I can run multiple processes using the same command, but which would search different files.  The plan is to make the command run faster.

Comment: Non-answer: pipe the list of filenames to `xargs -P` or GNU Parallel so you don't need to do the split manually. What do you have in `ictx`? Maybe I just can't follow what you're doing, but you seem to have the same pattern in both greps and the second runs on the file the first listed as matching, so at least it _looks_ redundant. (Also, I wonder if parallelizing will help with grep, or if it's I/O bound anyway.)

Comment: I do reads so that I can introduce the filename at the beginning.  ictx is the context (e.g. `-C 8`).

Comment: The three executions will be run concurrently.  The difference will be setting a different start index and a numeric skip,

Answer (score 1):

To select every third file from that output of `grep -l`, first note that you need to switch to NUL-delimited lists to be able to process arbitrary file paths (add `--null` / `-Z` option to `grep`), and then you'd have your choice of:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 'NR ~ 3 == 1'
```

```
sed -z '1~3!d' # assuming GNU sed
```

```
perl -0ne 'print if $. % 3 == 0'
```

Then, to loop over that output, it would be (with zsh or bash):

```
green=$(tput setaf 46) sgr0=$(tput sgr0)

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  printf '%s\n\n' "$green==> $file <==$sgr0"
  ...
done
```

You don't want to use `echo -e` as that would mangle backslash characters that occur in file names.

So, putting it all together:

```
green=$(tput setaf 46) sgr0=$(tput sgr0)

grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  sed -z '1~3!d' |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    printf '%s\n\n' "$green==> $file <==$sgr0"
    grep -ni "${ictx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "$file"
  done
```

But if the point is to run 3 of those loops in parallel each one processing 1 out of the 3 batches, then that's what things like GNU `parallel` are for:

```
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  PARALLEL_SHELL=bash \
    GREEN=$(tput setaf 46) \
    SGR0=$(tput sgr0) \
    PTRN=$ptrn \
    parallel -m0kj3 '
    for file in {}; do
      printf "%s\n\n" "$GREEN==> $file <==$SGR0"
      grep -ni '"${ictx[@]@Q}"' -e "$PTRN" -- "$file"
    done'
```

Here, passing the scalar variables via environment variables and otherwise using `${param@Q}` from bash-4.4+ to pass the array definition to the inner bash instances (here assuming the values don't contain any of the strings that are special to `parallel` like `{}`, `{.}`...).

Or maybe better, to avoid that limitation above:

```
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  PARALLEL_SHELL=bash TRANSFER_CODE=$(
    green=$(tput setaf 46) sgr0=$(tput sgr0)
    typeset -p green sgr0 ptrn ictx
    ) parallel -m0kj3 '
    eval "$TRANSFER_CODE"
    for file in {}; do
      printf "%s\n\n" "$green==> $file <==$sgr0"
      grep -ni "${ictx[@]" -e "$ptrn" -- "$file"
    done'
```

This time using the output of `typeset -p` to transfer the definition of all those variables (array or not) to the inner `bash`.

`parallel` will start 3 `bash` shells in parallel, each processing a third of the files, and recombine their respective output in order at the end.

In any case, running these things in parallel won't help if the bottleneck is the I/O (how fast the data can be read from disk).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128706/discussion-on-answer-by-stephane-chazelas-skipping-files-when-using-grep).

Comment: I am adapting the parallel version with my file stepping procedure with `sed`, inserting `sed -z '${sta}~${stk}!d' |` after `grep --null` line, and before calling `PARALLEL_SHELL=bash`.  Would that be proper ?