# Counting number of file matches from grep

Tags: bash, grep

How can a store the number of files matched by `grep` in a variable named `nf`?

Am using the following `grep` command, with the count being done by `wc`.

```
grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" | wc -l
```

Comment: Related - [Skipping files when using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/664821/100397)

Comment: Isabel, you've already got code to count the number of matched files, and in the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/664821/100397) you demonstrate you're using variable assignments. What's the problem?

Comment: What are your file names like? Can they contain newlines in the name?

Comment: I have done it with backticks

Answer (score 3):

The count for the number of files stored in a variable can be achieved by enclosing the commands with `$(...)`:

```
nf=$(grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" | wc -l)
```

An alternative is the traditional backtick:

```
nf=`grep -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" | wc -l`
```

Comment: nb: one might prefer `$(...)` over backticks. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Does `$(...)` define Command Substitution ?

Comment: @Isabel yes, `$()` is command substitution. backticks are deprecated (they can't be nested, and there can be problems with quoting) and only remain for backwards compatibility with old scripts, new scripts should be written using `$()`.  See also [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution)

Comment: That only works if file paths don't contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of files, and assuming GNU `find` (`-r` is a GNU extension in the first place anyway), you can tell it to print the paths of the files NUL-delimited and then count the number of NULs in its output.

```
grep --null -rl "${isufx[@]}" -e "$ptrn" -- "${fdir[@]}" |
  tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

Here using `tr -cd '\0'` to `d`elete all characters other than NUL (the `c`omplement set) and `wc -c` to count the number of bytes.

Alternatives with GNU utilities would be `grep -zc '^'` or `sed -z '$='` or `gawk -v RS='\0' 'END{print NT}'`.